# Loading strings divided by delimiter to array

Tags: c, arrays, delimiter

I have an array that needs to be filled with values from a string looking like this:

```
value0;value1;value2;value3;\n
```

I tried using `strtok()` but  couldn't really figure out how to properly load more than 2 elements into table.

Desirable output is something like

```
arrayValues[0] = value0;
arrayValues[1] = value1;
```

etc.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strtok() and realloc(). Both are a bit difficult to use

```
char input[] = "value0;value1;value2;value3\n";
char **arrayValues = NULL;
int N = 0;
char *token = strtok(input, ";");

while(token != 0)
{
   N++;
   arrayValues = realloc(arrayValues, N * sizeof(char *));
   if(!arrayValues)
      /* out of memory - very unlikely to happen */
   arrayValues[N-1] = strdup(token);
   token = strtok(NULL, ";");
}

/* print out to check */
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  printf("***%s***\n", arrayValues[i]);
```

Note that the delimiter ';' is overwritten, if you retain it as you specified you'll have to add it to the end of the strings, which is fiddly and probably not what you really want.

Comment: The program as such will crash, also `i` is undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just use good old `strchr` function to hunt for the substring `';'` terminator and `malloc` and `realloc` for memory allocations.

Make note that input `str` is modified (reused). In that string `';'` are replaced by `'\0'`.

(If you need `str` untouched than allocate another buffer, copy the `str` to it and point `p1,p2` pointers to it.)

The `arrayValues` holds pointers to the substrings:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char **arrayValues = malloc(sizeof(char *)); // allocate memory for string pointers

    char str[] = "value1;value2;value3\n"; // input

    char *p1 = str;  // init pointer helpers
    char *p2 = str;

    int n = 0; // substring counter

    // OPTIONAL if you want to get rid of ending '\n'
    //--s
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if(len>0)
        if(str[len-1] == '\n')
            str[len-1] = 0;
    //--ee

    while(p1 != NULL)
    {
      p1 = strchr(p1,';');     // find ';'

      if(p1 != NULL)
      {
        arrayValues[n] = p2; // begining of the substring
        *p1 = 0;             // terminate the substring string; get rid of ';'

        n++;                 // count the substrings

        arrayValues = realloc( arrayValues, (n+1) * sizeof(char *)); // allocate more memory for next pointer

        p2 = p1+1; // move the ponter after the ';'
        p1 = p1+1; // we start the search for next ';'
      }
      else
      {
        arrayValues[n] = p2; // this is the last (or first) substring     
        n++;   
      }
    } // while


    // Output:
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", arrayValues[j]);
    }

    printf("------");

    free(arrayValues);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value1 
value2 
value3 
------
```

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest form, if the string you need to separate will remain in scope during the time you are making use of the individual tokens, then there is no need to allocate. Simply declare an array of pointers with a sufficient number of pointers for the tokens you have, and as you tokenize your string, just assign the address for the beginning of each token to the pointers in your array of pointers. That way, the pointers in your array simply point to the place within the original string where each of your tokens are found. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 16

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "value0;value1;value2;value3;\n",
        *array[MAXS] = {NULL},      /* array of pointers */
        *p = str,                   /* pointer to str */
        *delim = ";\n";             /* delimiters */
    int i, n = 0;                   /* loop var & index - n */

    p = strtok (p, delim);          /* get 1st token */
    while (n < MAXS && p) {         /* check bounds/validate token */
        array[n++] = p;             /* add pointer to array */
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* get next token */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)         /* output tokens */
        printf ("array[%2d] : %s\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `strtok` **modifies** the original string by placing *nul-terminating* characters (e.g. `'\0'`) in place of the delimiters. If you need to preserve the original string, make a copy before calling strtok)

Note above, you are limited to a fixed number of pointers, so while you are separating the tokens and assigning them to pointers in your array, you need to *check the number against your array bounds* to prevent writing beyond the end of your array.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parsestrstrtok
array[ 0] : value0
array[ 1] : value1
array[ 2] : value2
array[ 3] : value3
```

Taking the parsing to the next step, where your original string may not remain in scope during the time your array values are needed, you simply need to allocate storage for each token and copy each token to your newly allocated memory and assign the starting address for each new block to the pointers in your array. That way, even if you pass your array of pointers and the string to a function for parsing, the array values remain available after the function completes until you `free` the memory you have allocated.

You are still limited to a fixed number of pointers, but your array is now usable wherever required in your program. The additions required for this are minimal. Note, `malloc` and `strcpy` are used below and can be replaced by a single call to `strdup`. However, since `strdup` is not part of all versions of C, `malloc` and `strcpy` are used instead. (but note, `strdup` does make for a very convenient replacement if your compiler supports it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 16

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "value0;value1;value2;value3;\n",
        *array[MAXS] = {NULL},      /* array of pointers */
        *p = str,                   /* pointer to str */
        *delim = ";\n";             /* delimiters */
    int i, n = 0;                   /* loop var & index - n */

    p = strtok (p, delim);          /* get 1st token */
    while (p) {                     /* validate token */
        /* allocate/validate storage for token */
        if (!(array[n] = malloc (strlen (p) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc failed");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy (array[n++], p);     /* copy token to array */
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* get next token */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* output tokens */
        printf ("array[%2d] : %s\n", i, array[i]);
        free (array[i]);            /* free memory for tokens */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(output is the same)

Finally, you can eliminate your dependency on a fixed number of pointers by dynamically allocating the pointers and reallocating the pointers on an as needed basis. You can start with the same number, and then allocate twice the current number of pointers when your current supply is exhausted. It is simply one additional level of allocation before you start parsing, and a requirement to `realloc` when you have used all the pointers at hand. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 16

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "value0;value1;value2;value3;\n",
        **array = NULL,             /* pointer to pointer to char */
        *p = str,                   /* pointer to str */
        *delim = ";\n";             /* delimiters */
    int i, n = 0,                   /* loop var & index - n */
        nptrs = MAXS;               /* number allocated pointers */

    /* allocate/validate an initial number of pointers for array */
    if (!(array = malloc (nptrs * sizeof *array))) {
            perror ("malloc pointers failed");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }

    p = strtok (p, delim);          /* get 1st token */
    while (p) {                     /* validate token */
        /* allocate/validate storage for token */
        if (!(array[n] = malloc (strlen (p) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc failed");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy (array[n++], p);     /* copy token to array */
        if (n == nptrs) {           /* pointer limit reached */
            /* realloc 2X number of pointers/validate */
            void *tmp = realloc (array, nptrs * 2 * sizeof *array);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc - pointers");
                goto memfull;  /* don't exit, array has original values */
            }
            array = tmp;            /* assign new block to array */
            nptrs *= 2;             /* update no. allocated pointers */
        }
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* get next token */
    }
    memfull:;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* output tokens */
        printf ("array[%2d] : %s\n", i, array[i]);
        free (array[i]);            /* free memory for tokens */
    }
    free (array);                   /* free memory for pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** you should validate your memory use with a memory use and error checking program like `valgrind` on Linux. There are similar tools for every platform. Just run your code though the checker and validate there are no memory error and that all memory you have allocated has been properly freed.

Example:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/parsestrstrtokdbl
==15256== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15256== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15256== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15256== Command: ./bin/parsestrstrtokdbl
==15256==
array[ 0] : value0
array[ 1] : value1
array[ 2] : value2
array[ 3] : value3
==15256==
==15256== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15256==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15256==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 156 bytes allocated
==15256==
==15256== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15256==
==15256== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15256== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**note above you see 5 allocations (1 for the pointers and 1 for each token). All memory has been freed and there are no memory errors.

There are probably a dozen more approaches you can take to inch-worm down your string picking out tokens, but this is the general progression of how to expand on the approach using `strtok`. Let me know if you have any further questions.